# Black backgrounds are transparent on Lollipop until app is installed a second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm having a bizarre transparency issue with my app on Android Lollipop (and only Android Lollipop).

Steps:

1. Uninstall any previous versions of my app.
2. Install the app.
3. Notice weird transparency on some fragments in my app (full-screen dialog, a fragment we slide in, our pull-to-refresh code).
4. Build a new binary with no code changes and install on the phone as an update.
5. Fragments all look fine.

Steps 1-3 I understand -- maybe some material theme is being applied inconsistently, or there's an issue with the custom themes we use in our app.

But I don't understand why re-deploying to the phone fixes the problem.

I'm seeing this on an unmodified Nexus 5 that got the Lollipop update over the air. I see the same issue on the Lollipop emulator.

I've tried changing our targetSdk from 19 to 21 and it did not help. minSdk remains at 15.

Has anyone seen an issue like this and can hopefully point me in a direction to debug?

Edit: Clearing data causes the transparency to return. Force-stopping the app and restarting it *fixes* the transparency issue. So I think cybersam is on the right track with his answer below -- there's some kind of issue in bootstrapping. But the fragments in question use @android/color:black and @color/my_app_black (= `#FF000000`) as their background colors, so I don't think the issue is in my app-specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but adding a values-v21 and changing my black color to `#010101` works fine. I have no idea what the issue is. Seems like an obscure theme misuse or an obscure platform bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to say for sure what is going on, but I can see one scenario that can cause this. It may be totally unrelated to your situation, but here it is, anyway:

(1) You normally depend on persistent data (e.g., stored in shared preferences, DBs, files, etc.) to determine how to display your background, and have a bug where you: (a) look for the persistent data, (b) see it's not there and use an inappropriate default value (e.g., null) instead, and (c) go on to display strange backgrounds due to the bad default value.

(2) However, you also have special code that detects the missing persistent data and initializes it with appropriate values. But that special code has a bug in that it does not update your in-memory state to match the stored values.

With the above situation, during a fresh install (and as long as the app is not *killed by the system* and then re-started), you would continue to use the bad data and see the bad backgrounds. During a re-installation (where you did not uninstall the app first), the system would kill your app and then re-install it without deleting its persistent data. Therefore, on a re-installation, bug (1) would not be hit and you would see the expected backgrounds.

Comment: Oops, hit enter too fast. That's really good analysis -- thanks for spending the time! Unfortunately I don't think it's my issue. The fragments in question get their backgrounds from an @color resource set to #FFFFFF. It also doesn't account for why this only occurs on Lollipop devices.